# Integral : from Summation to Integral notation

Tags: integration, summation

There is a question I found it is a formula, a Riemann sum, where the sum is in expanded form.
And the function(s) are rational functions.

> If $n$ is a positive integer, then
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \left(\frac1{1+\frac1n} + \frac1{1+\frac2n} + \cdots + \frac1{1+\frac nn}\right)$$
> can be expressed as
>
> (A) $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac1x \, dx$
>
> (B) $\displaystyle \int_1^2 \frac1{x+1}\,dx$
>
> (C) $\displaystyle \int_1^2 x \, dx$
>
> (D) $\displaystyle \int_1^2 \frac2{x+1}\,dx$
>
> (E) $\displaystyle \int_1^2 \frac1x\,dx$

SO, in this I did what can be called 'clearing of fraction' on the inside square brackets.
and then multiplying in the $1/n$, the resulting rational functions are of the form:
$1/(n+i)$ where the $i$ is the running index $i =1,2,3,\ldots$.

At first when I evaluated this as $n\to\infty$,
Realized it summed in a way that was not a nice number, it looked like the logarithm of a number you can say based on the expression.

I now think that this sum/integral may Diverge due to looking like a harmonic series, but that running index that I call $i$ and that $n$ is a positive integer, that eventually you take to infinity, is a key thing.

But trying to take this and seeing it as a Riemann sum and hence grouping the limit and Sigma sign to get the integral representation is where I am having difficulty seeing this.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the formula $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot k\right)$$

Now put $a=1$ and $b=2$ to obtain $x=1+\frac{k}{n}$ which means $\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\frac{1}{x}$

Edit: In your case the summation is $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. SO that means that as long as 'a' and 'b' are values that have a difference of 1 then I generate the DeltaX = 1/n.  And my f(x) =1/x

Comment: SO the f(x) in the integrand, is it just f(x) =1/x

Comment: So that would mean that option (A) would be the answer. And if it is, this integral would basically Diverge.

Comment: @Palu no they have to be exactly $1$ and $2$... answer is option E

Comment: See...values of $a$ and $b$ depends on the question...we choose them such that it fits our question...in this case 1 and 2 do the job

Comment: would not the values of b=1 and a=0 work.

Comment: I think I see now, we need to generate the rational in denominator to be 1+z, where z is our variable.

Comment: @Palu exactly...we need to generate the denominator in that way

Comment: Yes, I see. So we need to find the parent function, ahead of time, say f(x) =1/x, and hence use the details of Riemann sum to get the denominator to the structure we need.

Comment: @Palu not when you'll do a lot of practice :)

Comment: Hi, @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, thanks for your great help. Really appreciate it! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Palu your welcome

Answer (score 5):

Fix $n$ to be some large number. Then in the sum, the first and last terms give an indication of the integration range:

$$\frac1{1+\color{red}{\frac1n}} + \frac1{1+\frac2n} + \cdots + \frac1{1+\frac{n-1}n} + \frac1{1+\color{blue}{\frac nn}}$$

In particular, for very large $n$, $\frac1n\approx 0$ while $\frac nn=1$.

Now, if $f\left(\frac kn\right)=\dfrac1{1+\frac kn}$, it follows that $f(x)=\dfrac1{1+x}$, and in the context of the sum above we see that $x$ effectively ranges from $0$ to $1$. Hence the Riemann integral corresponding to the limit is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \left(\frac1{1+\frac1n} + \frac1{1+\frac2n} + \cdots + \frac1{1+\frac nn}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n f\left(\frac kn\right) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x+1}$$

and with a trivial substitution you can recover the correct integral from the given choices.

Comment: Yeah that's correct but that isn't given in the options...so in context of the problem ...the answer should be option E, right?

Comment: Right, "... and with a trivial substitution ...", namely $y=x+1$.