# Using the integral find, $\lim_{n\to\infty}[ \frac{n}{(n+1)^2} + ... + \frac{n}{(2n)^2}]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

This is question 1a in section 6.3.6 of Zorich's Analysis I.

I went about it as follows:

$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \frac{n}{(n+1)^2} + ... + \frac{n}{(2n)^2}\right] =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \frac{n}{[n(1+1/n)]^2} + ... + \frac{n}{[n(1+n/n)]^2}\right] =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \frac{n}{n^2}\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^2} + ... + \frac{n}{n^2}\frac{1}{(1+n/n)^2}\right] =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^2} + ... + \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(1+n/n)^2}\right]
$

This is the (upper) Riemman sum for the function $f(x) = 1/x^2$ on [1, 2] and therefore is equal to:

$ \int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2} - (-1) = \frac{1}{2}$

A quick numeric check with Mathematica seems to confirm:

```
In:= Limit[Sum[n/((n + i)^2), {i, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
Out= 1/2
```

Is this right?

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have *specific concerns* or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough

Comment: Another (partial) duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667576/integral-from-summation-to-integral-notation/